# CakePHP Translate behavior and pagination count

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, pagination

I have a model that has Translate behavior attached with two fields: title and description.
I have added some conditions at the translatable fields.
As usual in pagination, CakePHP first does a count and then fetches all the records.
When fetching the total records of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT( `product`.`id` )) AS COUNT
FROM   `products` AS `product`
   INNER JOIN `i18n` AS `i18nmodel`
     ON ( `product`.`id` = `i18nmodel`.`foreign_key`
          AND `i18nmodel`.`model` = 'Product'
          AND `i18nmodel`.`locale` = 'eng' )
   LEFT JOIN `categories` AS `category`
     ON ( `product`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` )
   LEFT JOIN `vats` AS `vat`
     ON ( `product`.`vat_id` = `vat`.`id` )
   LEFT JOIN `availables` AS `available`
     ON ( `product`.`available_id` = `available`.`id` )
WHERE  ( ( `i18n__description`.`content` LIKE '%test%' )
      OR ( `i18n__title`.`content` LIKE '%test%' )
      OR ( `product`.`code` LIKE '%test%' ) )
```

I get:

```
1054: Unknown column 'I18n__description.content' in 'where clause'
```

because the i18n table is not joined as i18n_*title or i18n*_description but as i18nmodel

However, when pagination tries to retrieve the rows of the query (not the total records) everything works normal. Is there any solution to this?

Controller code goes something like this:

```
$condition = array();
foreach ($search as $word) {
if (strlen($word) > 0)
 $condition[] = array('OR' => array('I18n__description.content LIKE' => '%' . $word . '%','I18n__title.content LIKE' => '%' . $word . '%',
                        'Product.code LIKE' => '%' . $word . '%'));
}

$conditions = array('AND' => $condition);
$products = $this->paginate($conditions);
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: I added the part with the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

This case can simply be handled by creating a custom paginateCount method in the Model you want to paginate.

```
function paginateCount($conditions = array(), $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {
    return count($this->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The paginator counter not uses translation joins so you have to join manually before find.
FindAll is not so good solution, because it runs comlicated queries, and eats server resources.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1753

A solution. It not works with SmoothTranslate Behavior, but a little modification of the code above, it could be work.
Override the before find.

```
 function beforeFind($queryData){
     if(!empty($this->actsAs['SmoothTranslate']['fields'])){
        foreach($this->actsAs['SmoothTranslate']['fields'] as $trkey=>$trval){
          if(!is_string($trkey))  $trkey=$trval;

          $joinFound=false;
          foreach($queryData['joins'] as $join){
            if($join['alias']=='I18n__'.$trkey){
              $joinFound=true;  break;
            }
          }
          if(!$joinFound){
            $newJoin = array(
              'type'=>'LEFT',
              'table'=>'i18n',
              'alias'=>'I18n__'.$trkey,
              'conditions'=>array(
                $this->alias.'.id'=>Set::map(array(
                  'type'=>'identifier',
                  'value'=>'I18n__'.$trkey.'.foreign_key',
                )),
                'I18n__'.$trkey.'.model'=>$this->alias,
                'I18n__'.$trkey.'.locale'=>$this->locale,
                'I18n__'.$trkey.'.field'=>$trkey,
              ),
            );
            array_push($queryData['joins'], $newJoin);
          }
        }

    }
    return $queryData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer, especially "Provide context for links" part.

Comment: Ok! Im newbie here :)